# build a project with the next-auth module returns errors

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, build, next-auth

I have a problem when installing the "next-auth" module.
I use yarn for my project with next 13 with react 18 and node 16 for the frontend.

My frontend works fine when I launch it with "next dev".

When I install next-auth with "yarn add -D next-auth", and I start my project directly, it works. The next-auth functions to connect work.

However, when I try to build with "next build" and restart my frontend, a huge error message appears saying:

```
frontend:dev: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useReducer')
frontend:dev:     at Object.useReducer (C:\Users\Desktop\directory\directory\apps\frontend\node_modules\react\cjs\react.development.js:1626:21)
frontend:dev:     at ReactDevOverlay (C:\Users\Desktop\directory\directory\apps\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\@next\react-dev-overlay\dist\client.js:853:969)
frontend:dev:     at ReactDevOverlay (C:\Users\Desktop\directory\directory\apps\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\server\dev\next-dev-server.js:120:12)
```

The error is very big.

You should know that this error also happens on the "useRef" function.
However, in my whole project I don't use either of the 2 functions (they are probably used in the dependencies).

I tried to remove all calls to the "next-auth" module in my code, but the error is still there.

Comment: while SO is also good place to ask, but if you are able to reproduce this error with empty project(only next + next-auth + some small set of pages) it might be much faster to get answer if you ask at Next's github